# ReactJS/AWS Cognito getting user input mid-execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a simple login page built with React that uses the AWS Cognito API to authenticate the user. There are some authentication scenarios (password needs to be updated, need to enter an MFA code, etc.) that require me to get user input mid-execution of the *authenticateUser* workflow. I'm trying to find a way to get the user input dynamically without using the built-in prompt() method, especially when a user is entering a new password. Based on how the *authenticateUser* workflow is structured, I'm trying to get all user input within the workflow.

Perhaps I'm not thinking about this problem in the right way, but **how can I have another React component dynamically render, get user input (new password, MFA code, etc), and then use that input within the authenticateUser workflow?**

The main Login component has a form that upon clicking the Submit button triggers the following function:

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isLoading: true, loginError: null });

    try {
      await this.login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
      this.props.userHasAuthenticated(true);
    }
    catch(e) {
      //alert(e);
      this.setState({ isLoading: false, loginError: e.toString() });
    }
  }
```

And then we have the login function that goes through the authenticateUser workflow:

```
login(username, password) {
  const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
  });
  const authenticationData = {
    Username: username,
    Password: password
  };

  const user = new CognitoUser({ Username: username, Pool: userPool });
  const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
    user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (result) => { 
        // User authentication was successful
        resolve();
      },
      onFailure: (err) => { 
        var error = err.toString();

        // If password expired
        if (error.includes('Password reset required for the user')) {
          var verificationCode = prompt('Password reset required. Please enter the verification code sent to your trusted device.' ,'');
          var newPassword1 = '';
          var newPassword2 = '';
          while (newPassword1 !== newPassword2 || newPassword1.length < 8) {
            newPassword1 = prompt('Please enter a new password.','');
            newPassword2 = prompt('Please confirm your new password','');
          }

          user.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword1, {
            onSuccess: (result) => {
              //Not sure if this handleSubmit does anything
              //this.handleSubmit;
              this.setState({ loginError: 'Password updated successfully! Please login with new password.', loginAlert: "success", updatePasswordUpdateAttribute: true });
              return;
            },
            onFailure: (err) => {
              this.setState({ loginError: err.toString() });
              reject(err)
            }
          });
        }
        // User authentication was not successful
        console.error(err);
        reject(err) 
      },
      mfaRequired: (codeDeliveryDetails) => {
        // MFA is required to complete user authentication. 
        // Get the code from user and call 
        var verificationCode = prompt('Please enter the multi-factor code sent to your trusted device.' ,'');
        user.sendMFACode(verificationCode, this);
      },
      newPasswordRequired: (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) => {
        // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new 
        // password and required attributes, if any, to complete 
        // authentication.

        // Get these details and call 
        // newPassword: password that user has given
        // attributesData: object with key as attribute name and value that the user has given.
          user.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword1, null, {
            onSuccess: (result) => {
              this.updatePasswordAttribute(user);
              resolve()
            },
            onFailure: (err) => {
              this.setState({ loginError: err.toString() });
              reject(err)
            }
          })          
      }
    })
  ));
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use the callbacks that authenticateUser provides to change application state? I don't imagine needing anything else mid execution except through the data the callbacks provide.

Comment: @IonutTrestian So I could perform some setState operation when I get into the mfaRequired callback that would render a UI component, get info from the user, and then submit that info using user.sendMFACode() without needing to exit the authenticateUser block? As in replace the prompt() with some setState that triggers other components and then have the execution of authenticateUser wait until it has gotten the user input?